# stylesheet.aspx does not exist?

Tags: testing

I get intermittent errors in my log files

System.Web.HttpException
Message: The file '/Stylesheet.aspx' does not exist.

I dont have this file in my code base. This error seems to be caused by .net not by any user trying to directly access this file.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You sure its aspx page and not css?

Comment: and does the file exist?

Answer (score 0):

I might start by using [WinGrep](http://www.wingrep.com/) on my project, and see where that text shows up in my code.  Once you find it you will probably know what to do to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some DLL or custom control you've lost track of is trying to load this whenever its parent is loaded?

You could use VS or a tool like [SadMan Search](http://www.sadmansoftware.com/search/) to do a quick search of all text within all files in the code base to see where it's being referenced and find the "source".